# ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES on a massive loop of https calls in react redux saga

Tags: reactjs, ajax, google-chrome, axios, redux-saga

I'm using react, redux saga and axios libraries.

recently, after loading lots of data to our database we are getting the ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES error message from chrome because of many requests per second.

it happens in this function because the messagesWithoutCheckedAttachments is has 1500 items:

```
const newAttachments = (
  yield all(messagesWithoutCheckedAttachments.map(({ id }) => { 
    call(http.get(`${CORE}/Messages/${id}/files`))
  }))
```

Is there a trick to add a delay or something so chrome will not need to handle too many requests per second?

first I tried to add  `call(delay, 1000);` like this but it's not working well:

const newAttachments = (
      yield all(messagesWithoutCheckedAttachments.map(({ id }) => { 
        call(delay, 1000);
        call(http.get(`${CORE}/Messages/${id}/files`))
      }))

and second, i am wondering if there is a more generic option to handle it so i will not need to refactor all of my methods. maybe there is a trick with the axios lib to handle lots of requests and send to chrome the requests with a delay?

I found that Github project that demonstrate the problem i have but i don't see a solution for that.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/ryanmr/err-insufficient-resources-demo)